# Valmiki's curse re-interpreted by Brahma as praising Rama

Tags: ramayana

Ma nishada! pratishtaanthvamagama sashvati samah!.. yat krauncha midhunadekam avadhihee kamamohitham!

*Original*

The cruel hunter was thus cursed when this sloka emerged extempore from Valmiki's mouth. His disciples were  also witness to the utterance.

*What I heard in addition*

Soon after this Brahma appeared before Valmiki and  made him aware that these very words constituted Ramayana in epitome with another interpretation ( even unknown to Valmiki himself !) praising Rama for slaying Ravana blinded with arrogant behavior indulging in worldly lustful pleasures. Brahma gave boons to Valmiki thereafter in order to make Valmiki feel every character so that he may write to record the entire epic authentically. He was also directed to a particular forest spot for this scripturing.

Is this also correct, and if so in which Purana is this double episode mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This episode is mentioned in Balakanda Sarga 2.

> Shri Brahma, seeing the sage afflicted and sorrowful, said to him: “O Great Sage, let these words spontaneously uttered by you, inspired by the death of the krauncha, be poetry. **Do you describe the whole story of Rama**, who is the essence of virtue and full of the highest attributes, in accordance with what you have heard from Shri Narada. Do you narrate all the known and hitherto unknown deeds of Shri Rama, Sita and Lakshmana and the asuras. Whatever relates to King Dasaratha, his wives, city, palace, sayings, conduct and what he accomplished, **will be revealed to you by my favour.** None of your words will prove false. Do you render into verse the sacred and delightful deeds of Rama. O Sage, as long as the mountains and rivers remain on the earth, so long will the story of Shri Rama endure. So long as the story of Rama endures, so long shalt you abide in the higher regions.”

Comment: Heard it from a Telugu social group. Thanks, it was after 67 years I now come to know the second part for the first time !